# how to calculate number of states for this logistics problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, artificial-intelligence

Consider a logistics problem with 3 cities, 5 trucks and 3 packages. Each truck can be at any of the locations. A package can either be at one of the locations or in one of the trucks. What would the number of states be if an atomic representation is used?

would the answer be 5 (num of trucks) x 3 (num of cities) x 3 ^ 8 (packages can be in a city or a truck) x 8?

I feel like this is completely wrong. Can anyone give me a breakdown on how to solve these types of problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each truck, there are 3 possible cities. This gives $3^5$ possibilities. Similarly, there are $5 + 3 = 8$ possibilities for each package. This gives $8^3$ possibilities. Thus, altogether, there are 
$3^5 \times 8^3$ possibilities.

Comment: Say you also had 3 drivers, would you just tack on 5 ^ 3 onto what was already existing? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I assumed that a truck could have several packages, but for drivers, maybe you don't want to have the three drivers in the same truck. You need to clarify the rules to answer your question.

Comment: Let's say you couldn't have more than 1 driver in each truck. would you just multiply by 3, in that case?

Comment: This is more tricky in this case. The first driver has 5 choices, but the second one only has 4 choices (since one of the trucks already has a driver), and the third driver only has 3 choices. It makes $5 \times 4 \times 3$ possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

For Atomic Presentation, the total number of states would at least be $n^{p+t}$, where $n$ is the number of cities, $p$ is the number of packages, and $t$ is the number of trucks. In this case, the least states are: $3^{5+3} = 6561$.